# Scala - how to filter a nested collection structure?

Tags: scala, collections

Here are my case classes:

```
case class Metric (
id: Long,
name: String,
features: List[Feature]
)

case class Feature (
featureId: Long,
name: String,
value: String,
processTime: Timestamp
)
```

Each Metric has a `List[Feature]`. I want to filter each Metric so that its `List[Feature]` contains only the latest Features per `featureId`.

I've tried the following but it returns jut a `List[immutable.Iterable[Feature]]` where the Features are filtered correctly. But I need it to reteurn a `List[Metric]` with filtered Feature lists inside it.

```
val f1 = Feature(1, "f1", "v1", Timestamp.valueOf("2019-07-01 00:00:00"))
val f2 = Feature(1, "f2", "v2", Timestamp.valueOf("2019-07-05 00:00:00"))
val f3 = Feature(2, "f3", "v3", Timestamp.valueOf("2019-03-07 00:00:00"))
val f4 = Feature(2, "f4", "v4", Timestamp.valueOf("2019-03-10 00:00:00"))

val metric1 = Metric(1, "m1", List(f1, f2, f3, f4))
val metric2 = Metric(1, "m1", List(f3, f4))

val metricsList = List(metric1, metric2)

val newMetrics = metricsList.map(m => m.features.groupBy(_.featureId)
  .map { case (featureId, metricsList) => metricsList.reduce {
    (m1: Feature, m2: Feature) => if (m1.processTime.after(m2.processTime)) m1 else m2
  }
  })
```

**UPD:** the expected output is a `List(metric1, metric2)` where

`val metric1 = Metric(1, "m1", List(f2,f4))` and `val metric2 = Metric(1, "m1", List(f4))`

Comment: can you post the expected output?

Comment: @Vamsi I've updated the question with the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a case class `copy` method on your `Metric` class.  This will create a new instance of `Metric` with the filtered features.  Note that you can also use `maxBy` so you don't need to use `reduce`.  To do this you'll need to supply an `Ordering` implicit to sort timestamps.  The below code should do what you're looking for:

```
implicit def ordered: Ordering[Timestamp] = new Ordering[Timestamp] {
  def compare(x: Timestamp, y: Timestamp): Int = x compareTo y
}

val newMetrics = metricsList.map(m => {
  val features = m.features.groupBy(_.featureId).mapValues(_.maxBy(_.processTime)).values
  m.copy(features = features.toList)
})
```